# Magento 2: How to get order information using REST API?

Tags: magento2, orders, customer, api, rest-api

I want to get **order,customer information by using REST API**.

Anyone have idea about this?

Comment: You want to get order, customer info using REST API?

Comment: Yes, I want order,customer info using REST API @KhoaTruongDinh

Answer (score 20, accepted):

For order information:

```
$userData = array("username" => "admin", "password" => "admin123");
$ch = curl_init("http://magento213/index.php/rest/V1/integration/admin/token");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($userData));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Content-Length: " . strlen(json_encode($userData))));

$token = curl_exec($ch);

$ch = curl_init("http://magento213/index.php/rest/V1/orders/1");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Authorization: Bearer " . json_decode($token)));

$result = curl_exec($ch);

$result = json_decode($result, 1);
echo '<pre>';print_r($result);
```

[Api List](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/rest/list.html)

Comment: I am using same code but facing problem in getting password.

For Password , $this->authSession->getUser()->getPassword(); 
but its returning encrypted password so rest api throw an error that you are not login properly. So, How to get decrypted password?

Comment: Password encryption is one way. So you can't decrypt.

Comment: But with encrypted password , I am not getting token here. So, How to get token with encrypted password ?

Error: {"message":"You did not sign in correctly or your account is temporarily disabled."}

Comment: How can I create my magento api to use this code snippet ?

Answer (score 5):

Go to http://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/

**salesOrderRepositoryV1** and **customerCustomerRepositoryV1**

- Order info: GET: '/V1/orders/{id}'
- Customer info: GET: '/V1/customers/{customerId}'

We can read more here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/149927/33057

Comment: but how to implement REST api ?

Comment: Read my answer here: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/149927/33057

Comment: could you please tell what are the parameters in body for the post man ?

Answer (score 5):

fetch all pending orders through REST API, add comments on it and change status for those orders

```
$userData = array("username" => "adminuser", "password" => "adminpassowrd");
$ch = curl_init("https://yourhost.com/index.php/rest/V1/integration/admin/token");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($userData));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Content-Lenght: " . strlen(json_encode($userData))));

$token = curl_exec($ch);

$apiOrderUrl = 'https://yourhost.com/index.php/rest/V1/orders/?searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]=status&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=pending&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][conditionType]=eq';
$ch = curl_init($apiOrderUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Authorization: Bearer " . json_decode($token)));

$result = curl_exec($ch);
$results = json_decode($result, true); // all orders with status pending

foreach ($results['items'] as $order) {
     $commentData = array(
        'id' => $order['entity_id'], //order_id
        'statusHistory' => array(
            'comment' => 'Received order?',
            'entity_id' => null,
            'is_customer_notified' => '1',
            'created_at' => now(),
            'parent_id' => $order['entity_id'], //order_id
            'entity_name' => 'order',
            'status' => 'processing', //assign new status to order
            'is_visible_on_front' => '1'
        )
    );

    $commentData = json_encode($commentData,true);
    $orderStatusApiUrl = 'https://yourhost.com/index.php/rest/V1/orders/'.$order['entity_id'].'/comments';
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$orderStatusApiUrl);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $commentData );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Authorization: Bearer " . json_decode($token)));
    $response = curl_exec($ch); //true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For Get Order Collection using REST API, You can pass below request url to fetch order data from Magento.

```
{SITE_URL}/rest/V1/orders?searchCriteria=entity_id&limit=5
```

Now based on above criteria you can get 5 order from order collection.

Comment: not work it return all result not only 5 records

Answer (score 0):

For any reason if you need to fetch order collection, a search criteria has to be amended to the URL. If you need to fetch all the orders, please use empty search criteria.

Example : http://magento213/index.php/rest/V1/orders?searchCriteria

Swagger contains more details. Please explore http://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/