# Consumer is not authorized to access %resources ? why

Tags: magento2, api

hi please someone guide me how to access api in magento2 , i think i am doing some mistake , i have made a test role and assign all administrator resources to it , now when i try to hit url 
(http://127.0.0.1/project/rest/V1/orders/)

it gives me following error

> **Consumer is not authorized to access %resources**

can anybody please describe step by step how to access api in magento2 ? i want to check orders coming in my database via api ... and wants to accept reject (change status of orders) via api , please guide

Comment: There is so much information online, magento even provides some information. If you don't understand it I'de say learn API first from scratch: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/get-started/bk-get-started-api.html

Comment: Have you decided what type of authentication to use?

Comment: i think i can go with third part Oauth api , because i want my gprs order accept machine to access it

Comment: Did you try to get your token via Admin account OR customer account ? please check this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/154198/magento-2-how-to-get-order-information-using-rest-api